# Changing separating character in Zend URLs

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, pretty-urls

Using the Zend Framework and the url method for the view:

```
$this->url(array('field1' => this, 'field2' => 'is', 'field3' => 'my example'), 'route_name');
```

Where route_name is the name of the url route and each field# is retrieved from the database.

I noticed that by default it changes spaces in Controller/Action names into plus sign so that what looked like:

```
www.example.com/this is my example
```

to

```
www.example.com/this+is+my+example
```

I would like to change the separatoer from + to - to have something like

```
www.example.com/this-is-my-example
```

I know that another thread: [How to change the separation character of Zend Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789129/how-to-change-the-separation-character-of-zend-url)
as documented a way to do it which I tried without success.

A thorough explanation on how to do it would be much appreciated.

EDIT2: I know where the problem lies if anyone is interested, it comes from the way the url is assemble, it uses urlencode which converts all non-alphanumeric characters expect - and _ and the spaces as +, there is no way to override that than replace the character create the url manually (as Maxime suggested) or create a custom url function replacing the characters (as suggest by aporat)...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of your code that does that ?  I have tried with a redirector like `$this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoUrl('/this is my example');` and I end up with `%20` and no `+` in the URL.

Comment: Just updated my post, hope that it makes more sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do that, you can extend the stock `Zend_View_Helper_Url` view helper and add your url logic into your view helper.

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

 class MyUrl extends \Zend_View_Helper_Url
 {
    /**
     * Generates an url given the name of a route.
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param  array $urlOptions Options passed to the assemble method of the Route object.
     * @param  mixed $name The name of a Route to use. If null it will use the current Route
     * @param  bool $reset Whether or not to reset the route defaults with those provided
     * @return string Url for the link href attribute.
     */
     public function myUrl(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)
     {

     return str_replace('+', '-', parent::url($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode));
     }
}
```

and then just load your new view helper and you're good to go:

```
        $helper = new \Application\View\Helper\MyUrl;
        $this->view->registerHelper($helper, 'myUrl');
```

Comment: It would seem like a good idea at first but wouldn't this also need to take care of trailing characters or what if some of the dynamic values have + included into them ?

Comment: After a second thought I decided to use the script you wrote. A way to make sure that only spaces or other alphanumeric (than "." and "_" and "-") would be to urldecode the url first and then convert them to make sure of a custom correction.
Alos parent:url does not work because URL is an helper in itself so it needs creating an instance of Zend_View_Helper_Url and then call the function url.
Then the custom function can be directly called inside of the view like $this->myUrl(...);
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't set anything before calling the `url(...)` function to achieve what you want to do.  The reason is that when the URL is assembled, it uses the php `urlencode(...)` function.

That said, you still have many options:

1) You simply don't use the `url(...)` function and create your URLs manually. (Best option)

2) You create a new helper that acts like `url(...)` but add extra changes to the function to achieve what you want to do.

3) You take the output of the url(...) function and do a `str_replace` to change `+` with `-`. (I DO NOT recommend that option)

Personally, I create all my URLs manually to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: You are quite right in saying that option 3 is not the best option (trailing character issues for example).
I will try route 1 and 2 and document what worked out for me, thanks a lot.
[EDIT]
I am not sure of what you mean by manually create your urls.
I think I went for a blend of solution 2 and 3 in the end.

Comment: By creating urls manually, I mean doing something like: `$url = "/page/{$var1}/{$var2}.html";` and then doing `<a href="<?= $url ?>">Text</a>`.  That way, you don't rely on a function that builds your URL in a way you want to change anyway and you reduce the overhead by keeping it simple.